# How to disabled particular field in Html using Angular-js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have my Html page having two field which are in state of disabled using **ng-diabled**.Here is my Html code:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="noteInputDiv" class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="noteInput">Lead Notes</label>
                            <textarea id="noteInput" class="form-control"
                                ng-model="userLead.fldLeadNotes" rows="4" cols="65" ng-disabled="disabled"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="caseNotesDiv" class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="caseNotes">Case Notes</label>
                            <textarea id="caseNotes" class="form-control"
                                ng-model="userLead.fldContactNotes" class="col-md-12" rows="16"
                                cols="65" ng-disabled="disabled"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here is my Controller code in Js file:

```
 $scope.onClickShowDetails = function(
                                targetIndex) {

                          $scope.userLead={};
                         $scope.disabled= true;

                            $scope.userLead = $scope.listresult[targetIndex];



                            // Triggering bPopup when click
                            // event is fired



                        },
```

where i used disabled scope variable.
What i Want to enable one of the html field onClick of edit button ,the function which is trigerred is:

```
 $scope.editCaseLead = function(
                                    targetIndex) {


                             $scope.disabled= false;







                            },
```

But problem is that Both field is enabled while calling that function,but i want to enabled Only one field.How it will happen as i am new in angularjs.
Any Help would be Appreciated in advanced.

Comment: use 2 different scope variables. Currently you're using the same boolean value to say if the fields are supposed to be disabled. maybe `$scope.noteDisabled` and `$scope.caseDisabled`

Comment: You should take two variables like $scope.disabled1 and $scope.disabled2 or something meaningful name.

Comment: sir ,but how can i changed the code in html file as i want both field to be disabled on One Button click and on another button click ,i want to disabled only one field,Can u elaborate the code Plz.. i'm new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use different fields for triggering the `ngDisabled`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="noteInputDiv" class="col-md-12">
        <label for="noteInput">Lead Notes</label>
        <textarea id="noteInput" class="form-control"
            ng-model="userLead.fldLeadNotes" rows="4" cols="65" ng-disabled="leadNotesDisabled"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="caseNotesDiv" class="col-md-12">
        <label for="caseNotes">Case Notes</label>
        <textarea id="caseNotes" class="form-control"
            ng-model="userLead.fldContactNotes" class="col-md-12" rows="16"
            cols="65" ng-disabled="contactNotesDisabled"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function disableLeadNotes() {
    $scope.leadNotesDisabled = true;
}

function disableContactNotes() {
    $scope.contactNotesDisabled = true;
}
```